# Use espresso with custom EditText

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-espresso

Here is part of my layout:

```
<com.rey.material.widget.EditText
            android:id="@+id/tagEditorSettings"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/circularProgressbar"
            android:hint="@string/tag_name_tag_settings"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            app:et_dividerColor="@color/my_primary"
            app:et_dividerHeight="1dp"
            app:et_inputId="@+id/name_input"
            app:et_labelEnable="true"
            app:et_labelTextSize="14sp"
            app:et_supportLines="1" />
```

and my testing code:

```
onView(withId(R.id.tagEditorSettings))
                .perform(click()).perform(clearText());
```

And when I try to run it I get such error:

> Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Action will not be performed
>   because the target view does not match one or more of the following
>   constraints: (is displayed on the screen to the user and is assignable
>   from class: class android.widget.EditText)

As I understand the problem is with "is assignable from class: class android.widget.EditText", but could someone please advice, how I can fix it and use in my case?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Issue**: [**com.rey.material.widget.EditText**](https://github.com/rey5137/material/blob/master/material/src/main/java/com/rey/material/widget/EditText.java) is extended from `Framelayout` and [**clearText**](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/testing/+/android-support-test/espresso/core/src/main/java/android/support/test/espresso/action/ViewActions.java) uses [**ReplaceTextAction**](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/testing/+/android-support-test/espresso/core/src/main/java/android/support/test/espresso/action/ReplaceTextAction.java) as

```
  public static ViewAction clearText() {
      return actionWithAssertions(new ReplaceTextAction(""));
  }
```

where `ReplaceTextAction` enforces the `view`, a type of `EditText` as

```
allOf(isDisplayed(), isAssignableFrom(EditText.class));
//                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Since `rey...EdiText` is not a subclass of `EditText` hence the error

---

**Solution** : create your own `ViewAction` as

```
public static ViewAction clearTextInCustomView(){
            return new ViewAction() {
                @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
                @Override
                public Matcher<View> getConstraints() {
                    return allOf(isDisplayed(), isAssignableFrom(com.rey.material.widget.EditText.class));
//                                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ 
// To check that the found view is type of com.rey.material.widget.EditText or it's subclass
                }

                @Override
                public void perform(UiController uiController, View view) {
                    ((com.rey.material.widget.EditText) view).setText("");
                }

                @Override
                public String getDescription() {
                    return "clear text";
                }
            };
    }
```

And later you can do

```
onView(withId(R.id.tagEditorSettings))
                .perform(click()).perform(clearTextInCustomView());
```

Comment: thank you so much! You have saved a lot of my time!)

Comment: @JohnA i am glad that i could help

Answer (score 3):

this custom *EditText* extends from **FrameLayout**. That's why it's complaining that the target is not assignable from class *android.widget.EditText*.

But, this custom EditText has some methods like **setText** to set the text in the contained EditText which is defined as:

```
protected android.widget.EditText mInputView;
```

and this one is an EditText from the android.widget package.

You can crate a custom ViewAction to access this public methods:

```
public static ViewAction setTextEditText(final Matcher<View> matcher,
   final String newText) {
    return new ViewAction() {
        @Override
        public Matcher<View> getConstraints() {
            return allOf(isDisplayed(), isAssignableFrom(com.rey.material.widget.EditText.class));
        }

        @Override
        public String getDescription() {
            return "Update the text from the custom EditText";
        }

        @Override
        public void perform(final UiController uiController, final View view) {
            ((com.rey.material.widget.EditText) view).setText(newText);
        }
    };
}
```

Then, you can execute the custom ViewAction:

```
onView(withId(R.id.tagEditorSettings)).setTextEditText(null);
```

Answer (score 1):

For kotlin solutioning:

```
fun setTextEditText(
    newText: String?
): ViewAction {
    return object : ViewAction {

        override fun getConstraints(): Matcher<View> {
            return CoreMatchers.allOf(
                ViewMatchers.isDisplayed(),
                ViewMatchers.isAssignableFrom(CustomDefaultInput::class.java)
            )
        }

        override fun getDescription(): String {
            return "Update the text from the custom EditText"
        }

        override fun perform(uiController: UiController?, view: View) {
            (view as CustomDefaultInput).textInputEditText.setText(newText)
        }
    }
}
```

Then you run with :

```
onView(withId(R.id.inputCityName)).perform(setTextEditText(newText = "Ab"))
```